# Unhandled 'error' event when extracting zip file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, wget, unzip

I want to download a zip file and extract it with nodejs. This is what I have done so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var wget = require('wget-improved');
var filesizeHumanReadable = require('filesize');
var unzip = require('unzip');

var downloadCSS = function() {
  var src = 'http://7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip';
  var output = '/tmp/7z.zip';
  var options = {};
  var download = wget.download(src, output, options);
  download.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
  download.on('start', function(fileSize) {
      console.log(filesizeHumanReadable(fileSize));
  });
  download.on('end', function(outputMessage) {
      console.log(outputMessage);
      console.log(output);
      fs.createReadStream(output).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: '/tmp/' }));
  });
  download.on('progress', function(progress) {
      // code to show progress bar
  });
}
```

The error message I get when running it:

```
mles-MacBook-Pro:test-api mles$ node index.js 
375.83 KB
Finished writing to disk
/tmp/7z.zip
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: EPERM, unlink '/tmp'
    at Error (native)
```

Now I'm a bit baffled how to handle the error event and what my actual error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the process have enough permission to write to `/tmp`? Does `/tmp` already have some files?

Because `unlink` is a node.js function to delete directories. Apparently, `unzip.Extract` calls it. So, `unlink` fails if the folder isn't empty (in your case `/tmp`).

Comment: You brought me on the right track. Yes, `unzip.Extract` tries to delete the complete `/tmp` directory. I needed to set the unzip location to a more specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the unzip location to a specific directory fixes it

```
fs.createReadStream(output).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: '/tmp/7zip' }));
```

I'm marking mostruash answer as correct since he brought me on the right track.